# contar radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas como puedo contar los radio butons tengo una lista

```
<td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
                        <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="">
                    </td>
                    si<td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
                       no <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="">
                    </td>
```

asi, son alrededor de 220 radio el id de los radio `id="check_1"` llega hasta los 220 
en la tabla que realizo el check_1 es si y el check_2 es no y asi va consecutivamente,  la pregunta es como puedo saber cuando seleccionan todos los que son si y todos los que son no, todos los radio tienen un name diferente para que solo pueda seleccionar si o no

Answer (score 1):

Hice una tabla con 3 filas y los checkbox que indicas en tu enunciado; lo que hice fue un evento **change** sobre los input tipo radio para detectar cuando cambiar o son seleccionados o deseleccionados y dentro de este evento te muestro como obtener los SI y NO que han sido seleccionados:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  let numSi = $('#check_1:checked').length;
  let numNo = $('#check_2:checked').length;
  $(".total-si").html(numSi);
  $(".total-no").html(numNo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   si <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value=""> 
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   no <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   si <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value=""> 
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   no <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value="">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   si <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r3" value=""> 
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   no <input style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r3" value="">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
    Cantidad de SI selecionados
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border: black 5px;width: 5%;">
   Cantidad de NO selecionados
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="total-si" style="text-align:center;"></td>
  <td class="total-no" style="text-align:center;"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Con un each en jquery para recorrer todos los input de type radio, dentro de este ciclo incrementar una variable solo si esta marcado

a los inputs les puedes definir una clase que indique que si o que no

```
<input class="class_si" style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_1" type="radio" class="radio" name="r1" value="">
<input class="class_no" style="width: 17px; height: 17px;"ut id="check_2" type="radio" class="radio" name="r2" value="">

var cont=0;
$('.class_si input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        cont++;
    }
})
```

otra opción seria la siguiente esta solo recorrerá los marcados
var cont=0;

```
$(".class_si input:radio:checked").each( function() { 
     cont++;
 });
```

esta forma es mas directa

```
$(".class_si input:radio:checked").length
```